# Access Cascading Combobox clearing after change

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I have some code to create a cascading Combobox in Access, which works correctly; the combobox filters to the list that I need.  However, when I change the combobox it clears automatically, so I cannot use it.

```
Private Sub cobVehType_Change()

    If CycleType(DLookup("VehicleType", "tblVehicleType", "VehicleTypeID =" & Me.cobVehType)) = "Miles" Then
        Me.cobMainType.RowSource = "SELECT tblMainType.MainCycle FROM tblMainType WHERE (tblMainType.MainType)='Miles' And (tblMainType.SimilarTo)=False"
    Else
        Me.cobMainType.RowSource = "SELECT tblMainType.MainCycle FROM tblMainType WHERE (tblMainType.MainType)='Hours' And (tblMainType.SimilarTo)=False"
    End If

End Sub
```

What else should I check?

Comment: Are you using this in a datasheet or continuous form? By 'clears' do you mean records will not display value? This behavior is expected on those form views where combobox saves record ID but displays related alias value (a lookup) because when the combobox list is filtered those values are not available for display.

Comment: @June7, it is neither a dataset or continuous form.  I mean the combobox clears itself - so it will not let me select an item.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the combobox list does not have any items? Try refreshing the combobox:

Me.cobMainType.Requery

Should not need the DLookup as cobVehType should have all the info needed to provide the vehicle type.

Comment: No, it has the items.  When I choose one of the items, it clears the choice and I can choose it again and it clears again ad infinitum.

Comment: Need to review form design, combobox properties, db structure. If you want to provide I recommend Box.com fileshare site.